# how does twitter manage which tweet to delete?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter

Hi this might be a very general question but i am open to all suggestions. I am using php, mysql and javascript in my code. How can i manage to find which tweet my client want me to remove? I mean if a delete button near the tweet is pressed how can i determine that remove button is associated with that tweet? I tried this but i couldn't get it going and i don't know what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Thank you

```
$sql = "select * from $user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>

    <div style="border-style:solid;
                    border-color:black;
                    border-width:3px;
                    position:relative;
                    margin-left: auto ;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    width:500px;
                    margin-bottom:5px;
                    margin-top:5px;
                    data-tweet="<?php echo $row['tweetid']; ?>
                    ">

         <?php echo $row['tweet'];?>

          <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deletetweet()">
         <script type="text/javascript">

         function deletetweet(){
         var twtid = this.getAttribute("data-tweet");
         $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "deletefollower.php",
        data: { twtid : twtid }
        });
         }
         </script>
         </div>
```

And php file

```
<?php 
start_session();
include 'connection.php';

$user =$_SESSION["myusername"];

if(isset($_POST['twtid']))
{
$uid = $_POST['twtid'];

$sql="DELETE FROM $user WHERE tweetid='$uid'";


}




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the ID in a data attribute:

```
<div style="border-style:solid;
            border-color:black;
            border-width:3px;
            position:relative;
            margin-left: auto ;
            margin-right: auto;
            width:500px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            margin-top:5px;"
    data-tweet="<?php echo $row['tweet_id']; ?>">
```

Then your event handler can access `this.getAttribute("data-tweet")` to get the tweet ID.